# Perspective / 3D screencast software

Tags: video, screenshot

I'd like to recreate the perspective / 3D effect of the mailchimp presentation video from: http://mailchimpacademy.blip.tv/
It's not the first one I see using this perspective effect.
What screen capture software was used to create this screencast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be Final Cut Studio ?

Comment: Can Final Cut Studio capture screen ? I'm not sure that's possible or perhaps you meant it was used to edit the video afterwards ?

Comment: yes, I thought about the editor tool. for capturing, there are lots of tools available.

Comment: It looks like you're right, I haven't seen any screencast software which can do that on its own and it looks like Final Cut is often use to edit screencasts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Camtasia Studio

Comment: Can you provide more details? I tried to achive it with Camtasia and I couldn't...